# How to obtain frontmatter (meta) from .mdx in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

I set up nextjs13 with ts support [and mdx according to the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#helpful-links).

Now I want to import the frontmatter in one file which was exported from another file. Is that possible?

`pages/post.mdx` contains

```
export const meta = {
  title: "some meta",
}
```

`pages/index.tsx` contains

```
import post from './post.mdx';
console.log(post.meta);
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

Expected output:

```
{ title: "some meta" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, [while stepping over a github comment](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/discussions/2075):

**Wrong:**

```
import post from './post.mdx';
console.log(post.meta);
```

**Correct:**

```
import post, { meta } from './post.mdx';
console.log(meta);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [front-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-matter), an NPM package.

Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import fm from "front-matter";

export default function SomeComponent({ markdown }) {
  const data = fm(markdown);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
```